# Show $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated

Tags: probability-theory

$(X,Y)$ are jointly distributed and $E(X|Y)=E(X)$. I need to show that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. I think I need to show that the $Cov(X,Y)=0$  but am unsure where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tower property of conditional expectation we have:
$$
\mathbb E(XY)=\mathbb E[\mathbb E(XY|Y)]=\mathbb E[Y\mathbb E(X|Y)]
=\mathbb E[Y \mathbb E(X)]=\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(Y)
$$
which means that they are uncorrelated.